# Video Analytics API

Tags: .net, api, analytics, computer-vision, video-processing

I am looking for an analytics solution that can give me loitering detection, line crossing, and people counting.

I prefer an API over an entire software solution due to the specific requirements of the project.

I have found two companies that provide video analytics, but neither seem to be in a hurry to give me pricing :P.

Is there any open source projects that are worth looking into? OpenCV is a bit too raw for what I want to do (well, I could use it, but then i have to write more code than I want to)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't much out there to get your hands on outside of OpenCV or derived works. Have you looked at [Emgu CV](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page), a .Net wrapper for OpenCV? It's pretty simple to setup to do common tasks like [edge detection](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Shape_(Triangle,_Rectangle,_Circle,_Line)_Detection_in_CSharp), for example. From there, you can build some more specific algorithms to meet your needs, which is pretty much what you are going to have to do when it comes to computer vision - general solutions are too unreliable.